# Adding gestures and making an image interactive

Tags: android, gestures

I'm trying to make an image more interactive by adding gestures (currently I'm thinking about only zoom, might add later depending on the requirement). It's a parking app by the way.

By interactive I mean that user can tap on a part of an image, let's say it's area A and labelled "A", and then a new interactive image will pop up for that area.

I'm pondering whether I should break down the image part by part in order to detect user's tapping location, or should I take the X, and Y coordinate? And if I should take the coordinate, does that mean I have to alter the code so that it'll cover different screen sizes?

Another question is.. I'm thinking of using Djikstra's algorithm for best route to be taken by user, does the algorithm need the image to be whole?

I'm also planning to add marks for vacant and occupied slots, but it is trivial for whether I should split the image to parts or not, right?

Comment: If it's only zooming, a lot of libraries are available for that. If you want more, explain it or search for libraries for it.

Comment: BTW do not ask multiple questions in one...

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I didn't know that we shouldn't ask more than 1 question. I thought by adding more questions in one thread, I'd reduce the number of thread. What about the image? About the zoom.. I had found it and applied it in my app and it worked well :D